# Embedded Document Viewer control in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

We are creating a search frontend using ReactJS. The requirement is that when a user clicks on a document's name, the document has to open in an embedded viewer. Has anyone used any ReactJS component for this? Otherwise, should I use a JQuery viewer component? Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

'react-file-viewer' can do the job done. it supports a wide variety of file formats including .docx format but fails miserably for .doc extension. correct me if i'm wrong, i couldn't find a component which can handle .doc file extension. finally solved with google api for doc viewer. i recommend to use it only to handle doc and docx file extensions. then go for comparitavely small libraries such as react-pdf to handle pdf extension.

you can render your doc, docx file types with in  using google api

```
<iframe class={filetype} width="830" height="400" frameborder="0" src={`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${file_url}&embedded=true`}></iframe>
```